# Haskell Functor implied law

Tags: math, haskell, functor

[Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) says:

"A similar argument also shows that any Functor instance satisfying the first law (fmap id = id) will automatically satisfy the second law as well. Practically, this means that only the first law needs to be checked (usually by a very straightforward induction) to ensure that a Functor instance is valid."

If this is the case, why do we even mention the second functor law?

```
Law 1: fmap id = id
Law 2: fmap (g . h) = (fmap g) . (fmap h)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I can't give a proof, I believe what this is saying is that due to [*parametricity*](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf), the type system enforces the second law as long as the first law holds. The reason to specify both rules is that in the more general mathematical setting, you might have some category **C** where it is perfectly possible to define a "mapping" from **C** to itself (i.e. a pair of endofunctions on *Obj(***C***)* and *Hom(***C***)* respectively) which obeys the first rule but fails to obey the second rule, and therefore fails to constitute a functor.

Remember that `Functor`s in Haskell are endofunctors on the category **Hask**, and not even everything that would mathematically be considered an endofunctor on **Hask** can be expressed in Haskell... the constraints of parametric polymorphism rule out being able to specify a functor which does not behave uniformly for all objects (types) which it maps.

Based on [this thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-January/thread.html#71631), the general consensus seems to be that the second law follows from the first for Haskell `Functor` instances. Edward Kmett [says](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-January/071672.html),

> *Given* `fmap id = id`, `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g` *follows from the free
>   theorem for fmap.*
>
> *This was published as an aside in a paper a long time back, but I forget where.*

Comment: Here is a more detailed writeup for going from the free theorem to the second Fnuctor law, https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/second_functor_law.md

Comment: @David There's a typo: "Fnuctor" -> "Functor"

Comment: As luck would have it, there's also always an arrow... ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Using `seq`, we can write an instance which satisfies the first rule but not the second one.

```
data Foo a = Foo a
    deriving Show

instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Foo x) = f `seq` Foo (f x)
```

We can verify that this satisfies the first law:

```
fmap id (Foo x)
= id `seq` Foo (id x)
= Foo (id x)
= Foo x
```

However, it breaks the second law:

```
> fmap (const 42 . undefined) $ Foo 3
Foo 42
> fmap (const 42) . fmap undefined $ Foo 3
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

That said, we usually ignore such pathological cases.

Comment: Note that when you discriminate with seq between different behaviors when bottom values are involved, you're "cracking" the type system. The haskell types form the Hask category, with functions being morphisms, _if_ you don't include bottoms. If you include bottoms in the picture, a manipulation similar to yours shows that the resulting structure is not a category (the associativity fails) so it doesn't make sense to talk about functors either

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the second law is not mentioned for validity reasons, but rather as an important property:

> The first law says that mapping the identity function over every item
>   in a container has no effect. The second says that mapping a
>   composition of two functions over every item in a container is the
>   same as first mapping one function, and then mapping the other.
>   --- Typeclassopedia

(I can't see why this first law implies the second law, but I'm not a skilled Haskeller - its probably obvious when you know what's going on)

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself -- it's not so obvious as all that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it was realized [quite recently](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/15382/focus=15384) that law 2 follows from law 1.  Thus, when the documentation was originally written, it was probably thought to be an independent requirement.

(Personally, I'm not convinced by the argument, but since I haven't had the time to work out the details myself, I'm giving it the benefit of doubt here.)

Comment: The link you provided seems to be about the uniqueness of `Functor` instances rather than the first law implying the second... [this thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-January/thread.html#71631) is about the latter.