# Does the First Functor Law follow from the Second?

Tags: haskell, functor

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8305949/977128) the 2nd Functor law is implied by the 1st in Haskell:

```
1st Law: fmap id = id
2nd Law : fmap (g . h) = (fmap g) . (fmap h)
```

Is the reverse true? Starting from 2nd law, and setting `g` equal to `id`, can I reason the following and get the 1st law?

```
fmap (id . h) x = (fmap id) . (fmap h) x
fmap h x = (fmap id) . (fmap h) x
x' = (fmap id) x'
fmap id = id
```

where `x' = fmap h x`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No

```
data Break a = Yes | No

instance Functor Break where
   fmap f _ = No
```

clearly the second law holds

```
   fmap (f . g) = const No = const No . fmap g = fmap f . fmap g
```

but, the first law does not.  The problem with your argument is not all `x'` are of the form `fmap f x`

Answer (score 10):

No, it only works in one direction.

Consider this `Functor` instance:

```
data Foo a = Foo Int a

instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Foo _ x) = Foo 5 (f x)
```

It satisfies the second law but not the first one.

The last step in your proof is invalid -- you showed that `fmap id x'` = `x'`, but this is restricted to `x'`s that are returned from `fmap` in the first place, not arbitrary values.