# Relationship between fmap and bind

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

After looking up the [`Control.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html) documentation, I'm confused about
this passage:

> The above laws imply:
>
> `fmap f xs  =  xs >>= return . f`

How do they imply that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Control.Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) says

> As a consequence of these laws, the `Functor` instance for f will satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

The relationship between `Applicative` and `Monad` says

> ```
> pure = return
> ```
>
> ```
> (<*>) = ap
> ```

[`ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap) says

> ```
> return f `ap` x1 `ap` ... `ap` xn
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> liftMn f x1 x2 ... xn
> ```

Therefore

```
fmap f x = pure f <*> x
         = return f `ap` x
         = liftM f x
         = do { v <- x; return (f v) }
         = x >>= return . f
```

Comment: Well, this just pushes the question down to the `Applicative` level. That is: why is `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` a consequence of the `Applicative` laws? After all, they don't even mention `fmap`! And then to answer that, you need @duplode's observation about parametricity...

Answer (score 8):

[`Functor` instances are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775139/2751851), in the sense that if `F` is a `Functor` and you have a function `foobar :: (a -> b) -> F a -> F b` such that `foobar id = id` (that is, it follows the first functor law) then `foobar = fmap`. Now, consider this function:

```
liftM :: Monad f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
liftM f xs = xs >>= return . f
```

What is `liftM id xs`, then?

```
liftM id xs
xs >>= return . id
-- id does nothing, so...
xs >>= return
-- By the second monad law...
xs
```

`liftM id xs = xs`; that is, `liftM id = id`. Therefore, `liftM = fmap`; or, in other words...

```
fmap f xs  =  xs >>= return . f
```

[epheriment's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105828/2751851), which routes through the `Applicative` laws, is also a valid way of reaching this conclusion.

Comment: I think the substitutions are more straightforward in my answer but yours expresses more of the intuition for why it *should* be.

Answer (score 1):

Let me contribute a more self-contained description of why this equality holds:

---

So, why is `x >>= (return . f)  =  fmap f x`?

This follows from the three monad laws and parametricity (for free). This means:

Consider the function `return :: forall a. F a`. Because this function must work over all types `a` it cannot not change or create new elements of type `a` but only duplicate or forget values of type `a`. Therefore, it does not matter whether we apply any function `f :: a -> c` to change all `a`s into `c`s before or after applying `return`.

On the left we apply `f` on the argument of `return`, on the right we apply `f` on the result:

```hs
return (f v) = fmap f (return v)                       (free theorem for return)
```

Similarly, consider the function `>>= :: forall a b. F a -> (a -> F b) -> F b`. Because this function must work over all types `a` it cannot not change or create new elements of type `a` but only duplicate or forget values of type `a`. Therefore, it does not matter whether we apply any function `f :: a -> c` to change all `a`s into `c`s before or after applying `>>=`.

On the left we apply `f` on the argument of `>>=`, on the right we apply `f` on the result:

```hs
x >>= (fmap f . g)  =  fmap f (x >>= g)                (free theorem for bind)
```

If we now simply instantiate g=return, we get:

```hs
x >>= (fmap f . return)  =  fmap f (x >>= return)
```

To this equation, we can apply on the left hand side the free theorem of return (`fmap f . return = return . f`), and on the right hand side the left-unit monad law (`x >>= return  =  x`):

```hs
x >>= (return . f)  =  fmap f x
```

Done.

Comment: I think answers aimed at Haskell programmers are probably more helpful if they use standard Haskell notation. I like proper quantifier symbols as much as the next logician, but not everyone learning Haskell is going to have the background to recognise `pure: ∀ a, F a` as equivalent to `pure :: forall a. a -> F a` (and in fact aren't you missing an `a →`?), and some will probably be confused wondering how the list-specific `map` and `:` got involved.

Comment: I was looking for a self-contained answer on this for functional programming in general :) , but i guess the question was aimed at haskell directly. I edited my answer -- do you think its better now?